# Are Hadiths the word of God and why are there Hadiths if there is the Quran?

Tags: quran, hadith

I have been suffering with weak iman lately and i keep on having these doubts

Comment: hadiths are the words of the prophet Muhammad peace be upon him. The hadiths complement the Quran. For example, hadiths tell us how to pray, how to fast, etc. They are advice coming from the Prophet peace be upon him. The Quran is the word of God

Answer (score 0):

1. Some hadiths confirm the decrees brought by the Qur'an. Such are the hadiths that forbid disobedience to parents, false testimony, and murder.
2. Some hadiths explain the decrees brought by the Qur'an and give complementary information. In the Qur'an, it is ordered to perform prayers, to perform pilgrimage, to give zakat, but it is not specified how they will be. We learn how to perform these acts of worship from the hadiths.
3. Some hadiths also make provisions on issues that the Qur'an has never touched. Examples of such hadiths that show that the hadith is an independent source of legislation can be given as an example to the hadiths that make it unlawful to eat the meat of domesticated donkeys and birds of prey, and that indicate many provisions regarding diets.

What has been told so far reveals the important place of hadith (sunnah) in the religion of Islam. In terms of religion, as a source of judgment that came right after the Qur'an, the hadiths were given due importance and Hz. Compliance with the Sunnah of the Prophet (pbuh), especially Allah (c.c.), and His Messenger, Hz. It was also commanded by the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) with very precise expressions. The following verses are mentioned in the Qur'an on this subject:

"Say, O Prophet: If you love Allah, follow me, Allah will love you and forgive your sins." (Âl-i İmrân, 3/31);

"Say O Prophet: Obey Allah and the Messenger. If you turn away, know that Allah does not love disbelievers." (Âl-i İmran, 3/32)

"Obey Allah and the Prophets, hopefully, you will be shown mercy." (Âl-i İmrân, 3/132);

"Whatever the Prophet has brought you, take it; whatever he forbids, refrain from it." (Hashr, 59/7).